# ASP .net Calendar moves components on the page everytime is is visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, calendar

I have an ASP page, and I have a calendar which is shown (set to visible) on the page when an image button is clicked.
The problem is everytime the calendar is shown it moves other components on the page down, and when it's invisible components move back up again. 
Could anyone give me an idea plz. Here is what i did finally: (Now its fixed)

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


    <asp:TextBox ID="CreationTimeTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">Creation Time</asp:TextBox><br />
    <script>
        AnyTime.picker("CreationTimeTextBox",
          { format: "%d/%m/%z %h:%i", firstDOW: 1 });

    </script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="EndTimeTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">End Time</asp:TextBox>
    <script>
        AnyTime.picker("EndTimeTextBox",
          { format: "%d/%m/%z %h:%i", firstDOW: 1 });

    </script>
    <asp:Button ID="btnResetSearchInput" runat="server" Text="   Reset search input" CssClass="resetBtn" Width="140px" OnClick="btnResetSearchInput_Click" />
```

Comment: Code you gimme an idea of your code plz

Comment: Hello to StackOverflow please read the FAQ, this question is not valid. Give us the code and the css ! You can make jsfiddle example too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I followed the following link and now im goood, [link](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#instructions)

Answer (score 0):

To not moving the rest of the page down, the calendar must a correct style that allow him to show as pseudo-dialog on the page.

The main attributes on the css that must be correct and set is the `position`, `top` and `left`.

Here is an example:

```css
.dialog {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:20px;

    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;    
    
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}

.NotDialog {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;    
    
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>Some other text before
     <div class="dialog">open as dialog</div>    
    and after the dialog
</div>
<div>
  Some other text below the blue dialog 
<div>

<br><br><br>
<div>Some other text before
     <div class="NotDialog">open by moving the text down</div>    
    and after the dialog
</div>
<div>
  Some other text below the blue dialog 
<div>
```

### More to read

[CSS OVERLAY TECHNIQUES](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/11/07/css-overlay-techniques/)

Comment: tnx for your reply. I did some css changes, plus i followed this line: [link](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#instructions). it fixed my problem